# Combine two rows in Pyspark if a condition is met

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark data table that looks like the following

```
shouldMerge | number
true        | 1
true        | 1
true        | 2
false       | 3
false       | 1
```

I want to combine all of the columns with shouldMerge as true and add up the numbers.

so the final output would look like

```
shouldMerge | number
true        | 4
false       | 3
false       | 1
```

How can I select all the ones with shouldMerge == true, add up the numbers, and generate a new row in PySpark?

Edit: Alternate, slightly more complicated scenario closer to what I'm trying to solve, where we only aggregate positive numbers:

```
mergeId     | number
1           | 1
2           | 1
1           | 2
-1          | 3
-1          | 1 

shouldMerge | number
1        | 3
2        | 1
-1       | 3
-1       | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to do a `groupBy` but only on the positive `mergeId`s.

One way is to filter your DataFrame for the positive ids, group, aggregate, and union this back with the negative `id`s (similar to [@shanmuga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811832/5858851)).

Other way would be use `when` to dynamically create a grouping key. If the `mergeId` is positive, use the `mergeId` to group. Otherwise, use a `monotonically_increasing_id` to ensure that the row does not get aggregated.

Here is an example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("uid", f.monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .groupBy(
        f.when(
            f.col("mergeId") > 0, 
            f.col("mergeId")
        ).otherwise(f.col("uid")).alias("mergeKey"), 
        f.col("mergeId")
    )\
    .agg(f.sum("number").alias("number"))\
    .drop("mergeKey")\
    .show()
#+-------+------+
#|mergeId|number|
#+-------+------+
#|     -1|   1.0|
#|      1|   3.0|
#|      2|   1.0|
#|     -1|   3.0|
#+-------+------+
```

This can easily be generalized by changing the `when` condition (in this case it's `f.col("mergeId") > 0`) to match your specific requirements.

---

**Explanation**:

First we create a temporary column `uid` which is a unique ID for each row. Next, we call `groupBy` and if the `mergeId` is positive use the `mergeId` to group. Otherwise we use the `uid` as the `mergeKey`. I also passed in the `mergeId` as a second group by column as a way to keep that column for the output.

To demonstrate what is going on, take a look at the intermediate result:

```python
df.withColumn("uid", f.monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .withColumn(
        "mergeKey",
        f.when(
            f.col("mergeId") > 0, 
            f.col("mergeId")
        ).otherwise(f.col("uid")).alias("mergeKey")
    )\
    .show()
#+-------+------+-----------+-----------+
#|mergeId|number|        uid|   mergeKey|
#+-------+------+-----------+-----------+
#|      1|     1|          0|          1|
#|      2|     1| 8589934592|          2|
#|      1|     2|17179869184|          1|
#|     -1|     3|25769803776|25769803776|
#|     -1|     1|25769803777|25769803777|
#+-------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, the `mergeKey` remains the unique value for the negative `mergeId`s.

From this intermediate step, the desired result is just a trivial group by and sum, followed by dropping the `mergeKey` column.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter out only the rows where should merge is `true` and aggregate. then union this with all the remaining rows.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as functions
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (True, 1),
    (True, 1),
    (True, 2),
    (False, 3),
    (False, 1),
], ("shouldMerge", "number"))

false_df = df.filter("shouldMerge = false")
true_df = df.filter("shouldMerge = true")
result = true_df.groupBy("shouldMerge")\
    .agg(functions.sum("number").alias("number"))\
    .unionAll(false_df)




df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (-1, 3),
    (-1, 1),
], ("mergeId", "number"))

merge_condition = df["mergeId"] > -1
remaining = ~merge_condition
grouby_field = "mergeId"

false_df = df.filter(remaining)
true_df = df.filter(merge_condition)
result = true_df.groupBy(grouby_field)\
    .agg(functions.sum("number").alias("number"))\
    .unionAll(false_df)

result.show()
```

Comment: What if instead of "true" for should merge, we had a mergeId. i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 where all the 1s get added, all the 2s get added, etc.

Comment: Added modified problem into the question

Comment: The same logic just update the filter clause to what ever you want to aggregate.

Answer (score -1):

**The first problem posted by the OP.**

```
# Create the DataFrame
valuesCol = [(True,1),(True,1),(True,2),(False,3),(False,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['shouldMerge','number'])
df.show()
+-----------+------+
|shouldMerge|number|
+-----------+------+
|       true|     1|
|       true|     1|
|       true|     2|
|      false|     3|
|      false|     1|
+-----------+------+

# Packages to be imported
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lag
# Register the dataframe as a view
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df=sqlContext.sql(
    'select shouldMerge, number, sum(number) over (partition by shouldMerge) as sum_number from table_view'
)
df = df.withColumn('number',when(col('shouldMerge')==True,col('sum_number')).otherwise(col('number')))
df.show()
+-----------+------+----------+
|shouldMerge|number|sum_number|
+-----------+------+----------+
|       true|     4|         4|
|       true|     4|         4|
|       true|     4|         4|
|      false|     3|         4|
|      false|     1|         4|
+-----------+------+----------+

df = df.drop('sum_number')
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('shouldMerge')
df = df.withColumn('shouldMerge_lag', lag(col('shouldMerge'),1).over(my_window))
df.show()
+-----------+------+---------------+
|shouldMerge|number|shouldMerge_lag|
+-----------+------+---------------+
|      false|     3|           null|
|      false|     1|          false|
|       true|     4|          false|
|       true|     4|           true|
|       true|     4|           true|
+-----------+------+---------------+

df = df.where(~((col('shouldMerge')==True) & (col('shouldMerge_lag')==True))).drop('shouldMerge_lag')
df.show()
+-----------+------+
|shouldMerge|number|
+-----------+------+
|      false|     3|
|      false|     1|
|       true|     4|
+-----------+------+
```

**For the second problem posted by the OP**

```
# Create the DataFrame
valuesCol = [(1,2),(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(-1,3),(-1,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['mergeId','number'])
df.show()
+-------+------+
|mergeId|number|
+-------+------+
|      1|     2|
|      1|     1|
|      2|     1|
|      1|     2|
|     -1|     3|
|     -1|     1|
+-------+------+

# Packages to be imported
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lag
# Register the dataframe as a view
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df=sqlContext.sql(
    'select mergeId, number, sum(number) over (partition by mergeId) as sum_number from table_view'
)
df = df.withColumn('number',when(col('mergeId') > 0,col('sum_number')).otherwise(col('number')))
df.show()
+-------+------+----------+
|mergeId|number|sum_number|
+-------+------+----------+
|      1|     5|         5|
|      1|     5|         5|
|      1|     5|         5|
|      2|     1|         1|
|     -1|     3|         4|
|     -1|     1|         4|
+-------+------+----------+

df = df.drop('sum_number')
my_window = Window.partitionBy('mergeId').orderBy('mergeId')
df = df.withColumn('mergeId_lag', lag(col('mergeId'),1).over(my_window))
df.show()
+-------+------+-----------+
|mergeId|number|mergeId_lag|
+-------+------+-----------+
|      1|     5|       null|
|      1|     5|          1|
|      1|     5|          1|
|      2|     1|       null|
|     -1|     3|       null|
|     -1|     1|         -1|
+-------+------+-----------+

df = df.where(~((col('mergeId') > 0) & (col('mergeId_lag').isNotNull()))).drop('mergeId_lag')
df.show()
+-------+------+
|mergeId|number|
+-------+------+
|      1|     5|
|      2|     1|
|     -1|     3|
|     -1|     1|
+-------+------+
```

*Documentation:* [lag()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) - Returns the value that is offset rows before the current row.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Steps are fairly clear and the `df.show()` at every step should makes things lucid. I think the code suffices.