# how to aggregate rows based on a condition in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to aggregate some rows in my pyspark dataframe based on a condition. Here is my dataframe:

| customer | total_purchased | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 4 | Maine |
| john | 3 | Nevada |
| john | 5 | null |
| Mary | 4 | Maine |
| Mary | 4 | Florida |
| Mary | 4 | null |

The result I'm looking to get will look like this:

| customer | total_purchased | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 9 | Maine |
| john | 8 | Nevada |
| Mary | 8 | Maine |
| Mary | 8 | Florida |

The rows that had a null location are removed, and the total_purchased from the rows with the null location is added to the total for each of the non-null locations.

Is there a way to do this in pyspark without involving very many steps?

I found a very interesting idea in this post (written by pault): [Combine two rows in Pyspark if a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811554/combine-two-rows-in-pyspark-if-a-condition-is-met)

But I wasn't able to implement it because there isn't a column to group by so easily in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter all null records, group by "customer" and sum the "total_purchased". This way it will work even if you have multiple null records for a customer.

Then filter all not-null records, join above dataframe and sum the "total_purchased" with joined entry.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["john",4,"Maine"],["john",3,"Nevada"],["john",5,None],["Mary",4,"Maine"],["Mary",4,"Florida"],["Mary",4,None]], schema=["customer","total_purchased","location"])

df_null = df.filter(F.col("location").isNull()) \
            .groupBy("customer") \
            .agg(F.sum("total_purchased").alias("total_for_null"))

df = df.filter(F.col("location").isNotNull()) \
       .join(df_null, on="customer", how="left") \
       .withColumn("total_purchased", F.col("total_purchased") + F.col("total_for_null")) \
       .drop("total_for_null")
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------------+--------+
|customer|total_purchased|location|
+--------+---------------+--------+
|Mary    |8              |Maine   |
|Mary    |8              |Florida |
|john    |9              |Maine   |
|john    |8              |Nevada  |
+--------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much. I was unable to upvote you because I am a new user and don't have enough points yet, but it was a very helpful solution and I implemented it.